# how to round number in java

Tags: java, math, rounding

please i need to know how to round numbers like this Example

```
1448 => 1450
1651 => 1660
22 => 30
1001=> 1010
```

so what function i should use to round number like this

Comment: isn't that trivial to write yourself? `while(x % 10 != 0) { ++x; }`

Comment: @Eugene you’d really use such a loop and not, e.g. `int m = x%10; if(m != 0) x += 10 - m;`?

Comment: @Holger :) _now_ I would... that was the first thing that came to my mind when I read the question.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if there is a special function but if you have the number `n`, then the number that you are looking for is `(n/10+1)*10` if `n%10 != 0` and else `n+10`.

So if you want to implement function on your own it would be something like:

```
int roundUpTens(int n){
    if (n % 10 == 0){
        return (n+10);
    }
    return (n/10+1)*10;
}
```

Another way is just to find the remainder when divided by 10 and use it to find round up number:

```
int roundUpTens(int n){
    if (n % 10 == 0){
        return (n+10);
    }
    return (n+10 - n%10);
}
```

Comment: It’s a very weird policy to add ten when the value is already a multiple of ten. I don’t know of any rounding mode that does that. Even weirder, if you insist on that policy, the extra `if` statements are entirely obsolete. The result doesn’t change when you remove them.